# if statement with datatables

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, datatable

Synopsis :-
Two datatables with lists of filenames in the first column.
Using filename in datatable A to "search" datatable B & update a third datatable with the results.

Struggling with the If statements to work with the foundRows part.

Any hints on how I can get this to function?

```
        // Iterate through the leftFileDT, extract the filename & search rightFileDT
        for (int i = 0; i < leftFileDT.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            // Extract the leftFileName & store it in a string variable
            leftFileMatch = leftFileDT.Rows[i][0].ToString();

            // Search the rightFileDT for the leftFileMatch string
            string expression;
            expression = "Right_File_Name = '" + leftFileMatch + "'";
            DataRow[] foundRows;
            foundRows = rightFileDT.Select(expression);

            // If no match is found
            if (notfound)
            {
                matchedFileDataRow["File_Match"] = "False";
                matchedFileDataRow["Left_File_Name"] = leftFileMatch;
                matchedFileDT.Rows.Add(matchedFileDataRow);
            }
            // If a match is found
            if (found)
            {
                // Update the matchedFileDT datatable
                matchedFileDataRow["File_Match"] = "True";
                matchedFileDataRow["Left_File_Name"] = leftFileMatch;
                matchedFileDT.Rows.Add(matchedFileDataRow);

            }



        // Report progress to 'UI' thread
        comparerWorker_Left.ReportProgress(i);
```

Comment: Calling `ToString()` on array is not going to help you. Instead use something like `bool found = foundRows.Count > 0`

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Select method of a datatable returns an array of rows that match the filter criteria.
If no rows match then the array is empty.

```
DataRow[] foundRows = rightFileDT.Select(expression);
if (foundRows.Length == 0)
{
    matchedFileDataRow["File_Match"] = "False";
}
else
{
    matchedFileDataRow["File_Match"] = "True";
}
matchedFileDataRow["Left_File_Name"] = leftFileMatch;
matchedFileDT.Rows.Add(matchedFileDataRow);
```